# Render Partial File AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code and I want to render my partial file inside a tab.

In my service.html

```
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">


  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Justified"><div ng-include src="sunday.html"></div></tab>
    <tab heading="SJ"><div ng-include src="monday.html"></div></tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in my app.js i hv the following code

```
angular
  .module('letsSchedulecommyApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.calendar',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cleaning_services/homepage.html',
        controller: 'CleaningServicesCtrl'
      })
      .when('/maid-cleaners', {
        templateUrl: 'views/cleaning_services/maid_cleaning_service.html',
        controller: 'CleaningServicesCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  });
```

this is my plunkr file `http://plnkr.co/edit/PgXGQFe8mDJ1lDkpEqrx`

So basically, i want to click on the tab and then view the rendered partial file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ng-include src should be in `'` single qoute, Add `ng-view` to get view angular $routing views on page.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Justified"><div ng-include src="'sunday.html'"></div></tab>
    <tab heading="SJ"><div ng-include src="'monday.html'"></div></tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
  </tabset>
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or put the source into a `$scope` var: `$scope.urlSource = "sunday.html"` - `ng-include="urlSource"` - either way, +1